# update multiple results in 1 database column

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to update multiple results in 1 database column first need to get previous values than update with new so far i wrote this query but it's not working see code query & current results

Code

```
<?php
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php' ); $mysqli = $link;

  $user_pages = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT actual_grand_total FROM user_pages"); 
  $actual_grand_total = $user_pages/100;
  $query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"update user_pages set actual_grand_total=($actual_grand_total)");
  $user_pages = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT grand_total FROM user_pages"); 
  $grand_total = $user_pages/100;
  $query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"update user_pages set grand_total=($grand_total)");

?>
```

database table "user_pages"

```
actual_grand_total | grand_total
------------------   -----------
       1000             750     
       5000             500     
       7500             750
```

> I am getting those wrong results

```
    actual_grand_total | grand_total
    ------------------   -----------
           1.000             1.000     
           1.000             1.000     
           1.000             1.000
```

> expected results

```
 actual_grand_total | grand_total
    ------------------   -----------
           10             7.5     
           50             5     
           75             7.5
```

can someone correct me ... i want to update current results dividing by 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do directly and using a single  query

```
   update user_pages 
   set  actual_grand_total = actual_grand_total/100 ,  
        grand_total = grand_total/100
```